# "if" "and" statements using ternary operators

Tags: php, ternary-operator

The following builds the link:

```
if ($cta) {
    $cta = vc_build_link($cta);
    $cta_href = strip_tags(trim($cta['url']));
    $cta_text = strip_tags(trim($cta['title']));
}
```

Currently, if `$cta_href` or `$cta_text` are empty fields in the backend, it will throw out undefined `variable errors`.

I'm trying to adapt my code with the use of ternary operators to make it more readable.

To resolve the `undefined variable` errors I'm **looking to do**:

if `$add_cta` equals `yes` (the user wants to add a button to this section) then check if  `$cta_href` and `$cta_text` are empty. If they're not `empty`, then show the anchor tag markup.

**I currently have:**

```
echo ($add_cta == "yes" ? '<a class="button " href="'.$cta_href.'">'.$cta_text.'</a>' : "");
```

But, I cannot find anything on the use of `and` within a ternary statement?

How do I go about this? and is my current pseudo code the best way to approach this?

Comment: same way as if statement.. the `AND` operator (`&&`)

Comment: What you want to do does not make your code more readable. Something like initializing the variables you use, would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just having your condition as you would in a IF statement ?

```
echo ($add_cta == "yes" && !empty($cta_href) && !empty($cta_text) ? '<a class="button " href="'.$cta_href.'">'.$cta_text.'</a>' : "");
```

A ternary operator is just

```
/* condition */ ? /* true value */ : /* false value */ ;
```

So you are free to write a condition as you would in a IF,WHILE, etc.. statement.

But ternary operator doesn't necessarily mean your code will be better.

Something simpler would be easier to read instinctively.

```
if($add_cta == "yes" && !empty($cta_href) && !empty($cta_text) ){
    echo '<a class="button " href="'.$cta_href.'">'.$cta_text.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: hmm, you're right, trying to reduce the lines of code doesn't make it more readable. Thanks for the advice + marking this one correct because the ternary statement works too